# is it possible to directly encode raw PCM in to Mp4 format in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

is it possible to directly encode raw PCM in to Mp4 format with aac  in android?  Without using android Media Recorder  i want to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

```
is it possible to directly encode raw PCM in to Mp4 format with aac in android?
```

Mp4 is a container which contains different encoders like aac, m4a, H263, x264. You can not achive this without using android media libraries. You can use AudioRecorder Class to record raw PCM data and using ffmpeg or libfaac you can convert it to AAC.